# How can I use attr<- with lapply?

Tags: r, attributes, lapply

Or put it more general: How can I add multiple attributes to the elements of list?

I am stuck trying to set an attribute to elements of a list all of which are `data.frames`. In the end I would like to add `names(myList)` as a varying attribute to every `data.frame` inside. But I even cannot get a static attribute for all list elements to go.

```
lapply(myList,attr,which="myname") <- "myStaticName"
```

This does not work because `lapply` does not work with `lapply<-`. If I had at least an idea how to do this, maybe I could figure out how to do it with varying attributes like the name of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I don't recommend it, but</s> you could do: `lapply(myList, 'attr<-', which='myname', value='myStaticName')`. An old fashioned `for` loop is probably the clearest way to perform this task---or do this assignment upstream when the objects are created.

```
for (i in seq_along(myList)) attr(myList[[i]], 'myname') <- 'myStaticName'
```

EDIT:

As @mnel points out in the comments, `setattr` in the `data.table` package is also an efficient option, since it assigns by reference.

Edit: @mnel -- don't use setattr with `lapply`. This is one case where the `for` loop is much faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
myList <- as.list(1:10000)

`lapply.attr<-` <- 
    function() 
    lapply(myList, 'attr<-', which='myname', value='myStaticName')

`for.attr<-` <- 
    function() 
    for (i in seq_along(myList)) 
        attr(myList[[i]], 'myname') <- 'myStaticName'

lapply.setattr <- 
  function() 
  lapply(myList, setattr, name='myname', value='myStaticName')

for.setattr <- function() 
  for (i in seq_along(myList)) 
  setattr(myList[[i]], name = 'myname', value = 'myStaticName')

result <- microbenchmark(`lapply.attr<-`(), `for.attr<-`(), lapply.setattr(), for.setattr())
plot(result)
```

[image]

Comment: +1, like your edit, thanks. Quicker than mine. Why wouldn't you recommend it? just because it is no performance issue and it's more transparent?

Comment: @hans0l0 Yeah, I don't think the result of this call to `lapply` is obvious at first glance. I guess it would depend on who's maintaining your code. It's very easy to write obfuscated code in R. I think the extra typing is sometimes worth the clarity.

Comment: You can also use `setattr` from the `data.table` or `bit` package that will set the attribute by reference and therefore be basically instantaneous.

Comment: @mnel Thanks, I forgot about that one.

Comment: `structure` is the copy equivalent of in-place modifier `attr<-`

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer by Thierry](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/114vz4ct7k/r-assignments-inside-lapply) I found a solution on my own. Actually I have been close with several tries but did not return the WHOLE list which is key.

```
myList <- lapply(names(myList),function(X){
attr(myList[[X]],"myname") <- X
myList[[X]]
})
```

My mistake was not to return the whole list but only the second line of the function, i.e. the attribute. Thus I was not able to replace the initial list.

@Matthew Plourde: what's strange: your benchmark looks somewhat different on my machine: RStudio, OS X, 2.5 Ghz Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM.
[image]