# Assign attributes with C++ to an arbitrary R object?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have started with Rcpp and I am working through Hadley's [book / page here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).
I guess these basics are more than enough for me, still though I missed, some aspect or feel that this might be less basic:

How can I assign attributes to an arbitrary R Object using C++?

E.g.:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector attribs(CharacterVector x,NumericVector y) {
    NumericVector out = y;
    out.attr("my-attr") = x;

    return out;
}
```

I understand I have to specify the type in C++, but still I wonder whether there's a way to assign an attribute to ANY R object that I pass... 
I have seen that `settatr` in the `data.table` works with C++, but seems to work only with elements of class data.table. Is there any way but writing an extra function for every R mode / class?

EDIT: The ultimate purpose is to speed up assigning attributes to each element of a list. 
We had [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614399/how-can-i-use-attr-with-lapply) previously – but it did not involve Rcpp so far (except for using it via other packages.)

Comment: I do not understand your question. FWIW the Rcpp Gallery has a post on setting attributes, and I have written a book on Rcpp so ...

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. Luckily Hadley managed to guess what I meant and answered the question.  The book's on the cart already. Nevertheless being eager to start and use things right away for existing projects makes me ask questions :). I think what confuses me is that a lot of examples use CharacterVector or NumericVector as function output type and not SEXP or RObject.

Comment: So you try to assign "whatever" (eg other R objects) as an attribute? In that case you do want to go via SEXP / RObject. Most problems and questions involve numbers so that's why they get the vector answers...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Hmm, I don't know whether "whatever" is really good idea. At the moment I'd rather go with assigning a key and store other related R objects in a separate environment. the attribute is rather a character based key to find the associated "whatever" object that resides in another environment. I have named lists with a lots of objects and I want to assign the name that an object has in a list just as attribute to that object. Just a character attribute called 'metakey'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this? `RObject` is the generic class for all R objects. Note the use of `clone` so that you don't accidentally modify the object passed in.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector set_attr(CharacterVector x, RObject y) {
  CharacterVector new_x = clone(x);
  new_x.attr("my-attr") = y;

  return new_x;
}


/*** R

x <- c("a", "b", "c")
set_attr(x, 1)
set_attr(x, "a")

attributes(x)

*/
```

Comment: You could use a `SEXP` in lieu of the `RObject` too.  In short, anything "assignable" as a `SEXP` should work, which in turn is anything we can wrap to a `SEXP`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel what's the difference between a SEXP and an RObject?

Comment: One is defined in a C header by R Core, and one is defined in C++ header by us. The nice thing about the latter is that `as<>` and `wrap()` take very good care of turning into the former.

Comment: @hadley the main difference is that an `RObject` is automatically protected from garbage collection. With a `SEXP` you have to do it.

Comment: @hadley: thanks, this answer the question perfectly. Also nice to learn about `clone()` in addition. I realized it might be helpful to add what the ultimate aim is and added it to my question. Eh, and could you explain why the output type of the c++ function is not SEXP or RObject? I tried your function using all of the three: CharacterVector, SEXP and RObject and the result was the same in R.

Comment: @MattBannert the only difference is how generic the function is (i.e. will it throw an error if you give it the wrong type of input). And given Romain's comment, I'd suggest always using RObject instead of SEXP.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my enthusiam: It's simply amazing how Rcpp helps an absolute novice to speed up code like that!

That's why I gave it a try though Hadley's answer perfectly covers the question. I tried to turn the input given here into a solution for the more specific case of [adding attributes to a list of objects as fast as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614399/how-can-i-use-attr-with-lapply).

Even though my code is probably far from perfect I was already able to outperform all 
functions suggested in the discussion, including `data.table's setattr`. I guess this is probably due to the fact that I let C++ not only to do the assignment but the looping as well.

Here's the example and benchmark:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RObject fx(List x, CharacterVector y){

  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector new_el;  

   for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    new_el = x[i];
    new_el.attr("testkey") = y;
    x[i] = new_el;
    }
  return(x);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to keep the modes in my R list?

Comment: I think it would be cleaner `clone()` to create a copy, and then modifying everything else in place